# Moneris payments by token in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, credit-card, recurring-billing

I am using Moneris PHP API for my client and doing a lot of monthly payments using this API. Each time when I have to charge from customers I have to pass their Credit Card info to this API request.

Now problem is that I never want to store credit card info in my database. SO I am looking for some mechanism in nmoneris by which I can only pass card info for first time payment. After that moneris should return a token for future payments. So using this token, I only pass some basic info when charging customer next time. (Basically I never want to send card info again and again).

I know recurring payment is one of solution for this. But in my case billing interval and billing amont is not fixed. That is why I am not using recurring payment.

Below is sample of code:

/********* Start of Code *********/

```
<?php
/*Purchase (basic)
In the purchase example we require several variables (store_id, api_token, order_id, amount, pan, expdate, and
crypt_type). Please refer to Appendix A. Definition of Request Fields for variable definitions.*/

// ------ Requires the actual API file.
// ------ the proper path
This can be placed anywhere as long as you indicate
require "../mpgClasses.php";
// ------ Define all the required variables.
These can be passed by whatever means you wish
$store_id = ‘store1’;
$customerid = ‘student_number’;
$api_token = ‘yesguy’;
$orderid = ‘need_unique_orderid’;
$pan = ‘5454545454545454’;
$amount = ’12.00’;
$expirydate = ‘0612’;
$crypttype = ‘7’;
// ------ step 1) create transaction hash
$txnArray=array(‘type’=>'purchase',
‘order_id’=>$orderid,
‘cust_id’=>$customerid,
‘amount’=>$amount,
‘pan’=>$pan,
‘expdate’=>$expirydate,
‘crypt_type’=>$crypttype
);
// ------ step 2) create a transaction object passing the hash created in step 1.
$mpgTxn = new mpgTransaction($txnArray);
// ------ step 3) create a mpgRequest object passing the transaction object created in step 2
$mpgRequest = new mpgRequest($mpgTxn);
// ------ step 4) create mpgHttpsPost object which does an https post
$mpgHttpPost =new mpgHttpsPost($store_id,$api_token,$mpgRequest);
// ------ step 5) get an mpgResponse object
$mpgResponse=$mpgHttpPost->getMpgResponse();
// ------ step 6) retrieve data using get methods. Using these methods you can retrieve the
// ------ appropriate variables (getResponseCode) to check if the transactions is approved
// ------ (=>0 or <50) or declined (>49) or incomplete (NULL)
print ("\nCardType = " . $mpgResponse->getCardType());
print("\nTransAmount = " . $mpgResponse->getTransAmount());
print("\nTxnNumber = " . $mpgResponse->getTxnNumber());
print("\nReceiptId = " . $mpgResponse->getReceiptId());
print("\nTransType = " . $mpgResponse->getTransType());
print("\nReferenceNum = " . $mpgResponse->getReferenceNum());
print("\nResponseCode = " . $mpgResponse->getResponseCode());
print("\nISO = " . $mpgResponse->getISO());
print("\nMessage = " . $mpgResponse->getMessage());
print("\nAuthCode = " . $mpgResponse->getAuthCode());
print("\nComplete = " . $mpgResponse->getComplete());
print("\nTransDate = " . $mpgResponse->getTransDate());
print("\nTransTime = " . $mpgResponse->getTransTime());
print("\nTicket = " . $mpgResponse->getTicket());
print("\nTimedOut = " . $mpgResponse->getTimedOut());
/********* End of Code *********/
?>
```

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vault feature of Moneris.  With vault you can store the card with an API call.  API return the Token so you can submit payment at will.